# Access different scope in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Might be a basic question but how do I access another scope within my ng-options? I can reach the scope with $('.nav').scope()

```
module.controller('dashLoader', function($scope, $http, timer, dashboard, alertSrv, $location) {
    ...
    $scope.elasticsearch_sslist = function(query) {
        ...
        $scope.elasticsearch.savedSearches = result.hits.hits;
        ...
    });
    ...
 };
```

I need to make a select field but I dont know how to access these values. This is what I tried:

```
<div class="span9 querySelect" ng-show="panel.queries.mode == 'saved'">
    <select class="input-small"
        ng-model="panel.queries.mode"
        ng-options="row._id for row in $('.nav').scope().elasticsearch.savedSearches">
    </select>
</div>
```

It doesnt seem to work

Comment: Remerber the first rules of angular : If you're using jquery, it's probably not the way to do it. If your select is in your html directed by your dashLoader Controller, you can access it with elasticsearch.savedSearches. You should provide a bit more of code. Especially your HTML.

Comment: I tried to do ng-options="row._id for row in $('.nav').scope().elasticsearch.savedSearches" but it didnt work. I will try to give more code.

Comment: I actually dont know which part to add...

Comment: I saw some ugly things from jquery devs going to angular, but jquery selector in ng-options goes straight to my top5.

Comment: Yes it is dirty. Thats why it may be good it isnt working. But I need to know how to access the other scope.

Comment: Provide the whole HTML linked to this controller. I'm not quite sure you actually understand how scope works. To fix that i'll need you to re-ask your question without using the word scope :) ! Should help.

Comment: The controller is set in the html tag.
    ng-controller="DashCtrl"

The other controller in the navigation menu. but i need to access variables from one to another.